# How to generate a sessionId programatically in Spring

Tags: java, spring, authentication, sessionid, jsessionid

My web-application is spring based. I have this job scheduled every one hour , and what the job should do is to create a sessionId and send it to another application. The purpose is to enable the other application to login to my system.

As far I understand, request.getSession() can be used if and only if there is a user request coming from the client. Since My job is a scheduled one, the user might not be logged into the system at all.

How should I approach my problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should approach the problem by not using session ID for anything.

The session ID assigned as a query parameter or cookie value is for associating a `HttpSession` object maintained on the server with a particular browser instance. It's internal and has no meaning to you. It may even change often, if you configure for very high security.

The session ID value has no meaning. It is just a token for identifying a *previously* created session. Sending an unknown token to an application is the same as not sending a token, i.e. the application creates a new session and returns a new session ID token for that session as part of the response.

Comment: I am a little confused here . My intend is to create a session for the second application and send it over to it, so that the second application doesnt need to create a session by himself.

Comment: basically I dont want my second application to authenticate himself. Kind of trying to automate authentication .

Comment: You don't do that by creating a session id... If that would work it would be quite an insecure application.

Comment: @Dalu Sounds like you are looking for a "single sign-on" solution.